# Entity framework many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

First model

```
[Table("Blotter.DealingDesk")]
public partial class DealingDesk
{
    public DealingDesk()
    {
        DealingStatus = new HashSet<DealingStatus>();
    }

    public int DealingDeskId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DealingDeskCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DealingStatus> DealingStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Second Model

```
[Table("Blotter.EmailAddress")]
public partial class EmailAddress
{
    public EmailAddress()
    {
        LUDealingDeskEmails = new HashSet<LUDealingDeskEmail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int EmailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }



 public virtual ICollection<LUDealingDeskEmail> LUDealingDeskEmails { get; set; }
 }
```

Third Model(Look up table as POCO)

```
[Table("Blotter.LUDealingDeskEmail")]
public partial class LUDealingDeskEmail
{
    public int LUDealingDeskEmailId { get; set; }

    public int FK_EmailId { get; set; }

    public int FK_DealingDeskId { get; set; }

    public virtual DealingDesk DealingDesk { get; set; }

    public virtual EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
}



public partial class MCUtilityContext : DbContext
{
    public MCUtilityContext()
        : base("name=MCUtilityContext")
    { 
        Database.SetInitializer<CapstoneInterfaceContext>(null);

        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DealingDesk> DealingDesks { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<DealingStatus> DealingStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<LUDealingDeskEmail> LUDealingDeskEmails { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationError> ApplicationErrors { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DealingDesk>()
            .HasKey(k => k.DealingDeskId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DealingStatus>()
            .HasKey(k => k.DealingStatusId)
            .HasRequired(e => e.DealingDesk)
            .WithMany( s => s.DealingStatus)
            .HasForeignKey( s => s.DealingDeskId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        //modelBuilder.Entity<DealingDesk>()
        //    .HasMany(a => a.EmailAddress)
        //    .WithMany(b => b.)
        //    .Map(m =>
        //    {
        //        m.MapLeftKey("DealingDeskId");
        //        m.MapRightKey("EmailId");
        //        m.ToTable("LUDealingDeskEmail", "Blotter");

        //    });

            //modelBuilder.Entity<DealingDesk>()
            //     .HasMany<EmailAddress>(s => s.EmailAddress)
            //     .WithMany(c => c.DealingDesk)
            //     .Map(cs =>
            //     {
            //         cs.MapLeftKey("FK_DealingDeskId");
            //         cs.MapRightKey("FK_EmailId");
            //         cs.ToTable("Blotter.LUDealingDeskEmail");
            //     });

    }
```

The problem is when I retrieve the dealing desk object I don’t get the emails it comes back with an error saying:

> '((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.DealingDesk_B97FADE5FCA3BA8DED564B236CAB94E3462E9228525392A5055AE860F8156F86)
>   new
>   System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(dealingDesk).Items[1]).EmailAddress'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

maybe I’m looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error, when I were trying to access foreign key object, without calling ToList() on the query resulting sequence. Here is example:

```
class ForeignKeyObject
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
}

class Entity
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public ForeignKeyObj KeyObj{get;set;}
}
```

Here is code to reproduce the error:

```
var entities = (from e in _db.Entities
                                 where e.Id== 1
                                 select e).ToList();
foreach( var e in entities )
      Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyObj.Id.ToString());
```

Error will manifest itself on Debug.WriteLine() line, if ToList() call would be removed. Add it back and EF will populate foreign key object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: @BhargavRao With all due respect, it **IS** an answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao It was flagged too soon.

Comment: Nope, there are users who flag as soon as you post. So, Henceforth please post the complete answer at the first attempt. There might be users who directly flag the answer w/o commenting, and you might lose out on your good points. Take care next time

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for explanation. This practice looks a bit bizarre to me, but I guess it is what it is.:) Next time I would be more careful.

Comment: Np, Use the site for a few more days and you will get to know about it. All the best. :-)